# Doxygen: multiple use of section label bug?

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I use Doxygen to document my code and I encounter a problem when I use the markdown syntax.

For example, I have two `.dox` files:

fileABC.dox:

```
/**
@page abcPage

Header {#abcHeader}
======

abc Text.
*/
```

fileDEF.dox

```
/**
@page defPage

Header {#defHeader}
======

def Text.
*/
```

Which raise the warning:

```
warning: multiple use of section label 'Header'
```

and the `abcHeader` section is not generated.

There is two workaround, but none of them is ok for me:

- Rename the section to `ABC Header` and `DEF Header`
- Or go back to the Doxygen syntax `@section abcHeader Header`

So, is there another way to use the same section name in several pages, with the Markdown syntax ?

### EDIT

This bug has been introduced in version `1.8.7` : [View commit](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/ac611be473c2d9bf65bcafb53b0577274c4ae706)

It seems to be more a bug than a new feature or improvement since the *setext-syntax* (using # instead of ==) does not give a warning when the same section name is used several times.

Comment: Can't reproduce this in Doxygen 1.8.6 on Ubuntu 14.04x64. Which version of Doxygen do you use?

Comment: I tested with `v1.8.4` ( => no bug) and `v1.8.7` ( => bug present)

Comment: Wait. 1.8.4 _does not_ contain the bug, whereas _1.8.7_ does? Well, then it's probably a defect introduced by 1.8.7, unless 1.8.6. also doesn't produce your desired output. Check the 1.8.7 changelog, maybe there's a hint.

Comment: Yes I confirm: `1.8.4` does not contain the bug. I will check the changelog.

Comment: I found this commit : https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/ee830bb8888535ac48c0c4fd90580542e7f70481 which may (or may not) be related. And when I use the setex-syntax (instead of the atx one) I do not have the bug.

Comment: [This change](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/ac611be473c2d9bf65bcafb53b0577274c4ae706) introduced the warning message on same section name in the `1.8.7` release.

Comment: Looks to me that the problem has been solved in version 1.8.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug introduced in version 1.8.7 and resolved in version 1.8.8

[Bug description](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=735001) -- [fix](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/ebb2fe6d73b4aefc6dadab8eec45adc4ee0c9fd5)